# C++ openGL VBO crashes program

Tags: c++, opengl

I recently created an OBJ loader, it works perfectly fine at the moment, which is without any VBO buffer objects. I am currently in the process of changing over to using VBO with my program and it crashes( doesn't respond) every time I try to run it.

My obj loader consists of drawing the normals and verts, it has the indicies aswell.

I am new to openGL and I somewhat have an idea of how VBO works.

This is it when I have made an attempt to add buffers to my program.

[image]

This is it without

[image]

This is my code that is currently crashing

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);

    glutCreateWindow("Object Loader!");
    setUpArrays();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);


    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(normals), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLfloat posLight0[] = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f};
    GLfloat lightColor[] = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, posLight0);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, lightColor);



    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeys);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);


    glutTimerFunc(25,update,0);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

This is my draw function

```
void Draw(void)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glRotatef( rotate_x, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
    glRotatef( rotate_y, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,0, vertices);


    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.8f);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, amountOfFaces, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);


    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

These are the only two functions that I have changed,
I've defined the unsigned int vbo and vbo2 outside.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (and cause of the crash) is that your `glVertexPointer` should have 0 as the offset because it is relative tot the beginning of the bound buffer. (0 is a special case that treats program memory as one big buffer)

```
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(normals), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

That is another problem; the 4th line `glBindBuffer` fully overrides the previous call to `glBindBuffer`. Or more generally; only the last `glBindBuffer` call is used so you never actually use `vbo`.

Also how are `vertices` and `normals` declared? if they are just pointers then you should replace sizeof with `sizeof(*vertices)*3*amountOfFaces`

Comment: The true reason is, because OP doesn't initialize the function pointers. VBOs have been introduced into core only with OpenGL-3, before that its an extension. Either must be initialized. Also glVertexPointer takes arbitrary integer values for the pointer argument even with VBOs enabled. I normally consider your answers high quality, but this time you're wayyy off.

Comment: @datenwolf unless glut initializes the function pointers for him

Comment: GLUT doesn't do this. Neither does OpenGLUT nor FreeGLUT; FreeGLUT includes a command for testing if an extension is supported and a portable wrapper around `…GetProcAddress`, but it doesn't actually load the pointers.

Comment: Hey guys, I'm not quite sure about what the function pointers are, if one of you could elaborate I would be grateful. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample indicates that you're trying to use GLEW, but you haven't called `glewInit` after `glutCreateWindow`. You can't use OpenGL extension functions without loading their addresses first - that's exactly what GLEW do, if you don't want to mess with it manually (most likely you don't).

Your code appears to be wrong even after that, but it probably wouldn't crash. Can't say without full code of course, but

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2);
```

Don't making sense - bind one buffer, then immediately another - why is that?